# Add image to 2nd window of Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, image, tkinter

This code will open a main window with an image, then another window with the same image. However, the code below results in this error:

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ambbrash/fp.py", line 31, in MenuWin
    self.record = Menu()
  File "/home/ambbrash/fp.py", line 44, in __init__
    tktext_label.image = photo
NameError: name 'photo' is not defined
```

Any advice on how to fix this?
Also, is there any way to resize the image?

Here is the code:

```
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('4 Dry Out')
# IMAGE 1 (1st window)
img=PhotoImage(file='4 Dry Out Logo.png')
Label(root,image=img).pack()
# window format
root.geometry("275x75")
root['bg']='blue'

class MainWin:
    # main window frame
    def __init__(self, master):
        mainFrame = Frame(master)
        mainFrame.pack()
        # main window title / button 
        self.titleLabel = Label(master, text="4 Dry Out e-Rental", bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Arial Black", 20))
        self.titleLabel.pack()
        self.Btn = Button(master, text="Water Damage Equipment", command=self.MenuWin, bg="navy", fg="white", font=("Roboto")).pack()

        # IMAGE 2 (2nd window)
       # img = PhotoImage(file = '4 Dry Out Logo.png')
       # Label(win, image=img).pack()        
    # button: new window
    def MenuWin(self):
        self.record = Menu()
        self.record.win.mainloop()
        
class Menu:
    # new window frame 
    def __init__(self):
        self.win = Toplevel()
        self.frameFit = Frame(self.win)
        self.frameFit.pack()
        self.frameFit['bg']='blue'
        # image 
        img=PhotoImage(file='4 Dry Out Logo.png')
        Label(self.win,image=img).pack()
        tktext_label.image = photo
        # portal title 
        self.TitleLabel = Label(self.frameFit, text="e-Rental Portal", bg="blue", fg="white", font=("Arial Black",15)).pack()
        
# start / end             
winStart = MainWin(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: please provide a [mre] and the **full error traceback** (starting at word "Traceback") (you can [edit] your question)

Comment: One big problem is that you are importing a "Menu" class but also defining one. It's for this reason that PEP8 recommends you do not use wildcard imports. Use `import tkinter as tk` instead. Another problem is that you have `mainloop()` call twice. That should only happen once in your entire program.

Comment: The error means that at some point you provided `self` instead of `self.framefit` as the master.

Comment: @Novel Should I delete the mainloop() in the def MenuWin? Also if I change to import tkinter as tk the program doesn't run. How do I go about formatting this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a code where you even use the image. For example:

```
img = PhotoImage(file = 'myimage.png')
Label(win, image=img).pack()
```

In your case you haven't used the image declared as `img`. You need to either place the file in a label or button.

Thank You!

Comment: To place the image in the 2nd window, should I use 'root' ?

Comment: if root is your second window then yes. If it is the Tk() then you need to put it in the second window and not root.

Comment: I input the code how you displayed. Root is the main window, I thought the 2nd window was 'Win'. However, if I name it 'tk', 'win', 'self', they all report error messages like what's in the updated post ^

Comment: I am sure self and tk will not work. Try putting either win or self.win if 'win' is the name of the 2nd window

Comment: self.win is getting the image to show up. However, it still gives an error "Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/tkinter/__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/ambbrash/fp.py", line 31, in MenuWin
    self.record = Menu()
  File "/home/ambbrash/fp.py", line 44, in __init__
    tktext_label.image = photo
NameError: name 'photo' is not defined"